# Pl/SQL oracle functions

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I am tryin to compare last name between SRC and target table, names are same but they might have extra spaces or character, how do i ignore that? Is this the best way to do the comparison
  ltrim(rtrim(upper(substr(PERSON_LAST_NAME,1,3))))=ltrim(rtrim(upper(substr(CUST_LAST_NAME,1,3))))

Comment: Hey there...what is the reason for the (1,3) start and end points?

Comment: I am thinkin "trim()" and "like" might work.

Comment: hey kaushik I want to compare upto 3 char only, so that there are more chances of matches

Answer (score 0):

You must before Trim and then substr string as follow

upper(substr(ltrim(rtrim(PERSON_LAST_NAME)),1,3))=upper(substr(ltrim(rtrim(CUST_LAST_NAME)),1,3))

hope this help